# OnTouchListener not working fine

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onresume

I have some problems with `OnTouchListener`. I want that everytime when user touch the screen to go to a certain activity. The problem is that when I touch the screen it is making something like an refresh for the present activity and it starts (the current activity contains a `ViewFlipper` and when the screen is touched the viewflipper starts flipping from the begining). Only at the second touch the app goes to next activity. Can anyone help me to solve this?

My current activity extends `OnTouchListener` , I set `myviewflipper.setonTouchListener(this)` and my `onTouch()` method is :

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            finish=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FinishApplication.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

After I touch the screen is called `onPause()` and `onResume()`. On `onResume()` method I start some timers for some updates (when updates are made, the slideshow starts) and I think that's the reason why my activity is refresh. I set a variable boolean `finish` to `true` only after the screen is touch and start the updates only if `finish` is `false` but is not working. My variable is not set to true. Any other idea how can I solve this ?

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("OnResume ViewPlaylist!!");
        t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Imalive();
                    }
                });

            }

        }, 300, 30000);

        if (finish != true) {
            System.out.println("Start update!");
            update = new Timer();
            update.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            updateItems();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }, 30000, 20000);
        } else {
            finish = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(SlideShow.this, FinishApplication.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


}
}
```

Comment: have you run your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by calling `finish()` on `onPause()` method.